# Confused by "...extends Function1[Int, Int]"

Tags: scala

In the twitter Scala School "Basics Continued" http://twitter.github.io/scala_school/basics2.html there is the following Object definintion

```
object addOne extends Function1[Int, Int] {
  def apply(m: Int): Int = m + 1
}
```

I don't fully understand the [Int, Int] type parameterization.  When we extends Function1, I believe I am declaring that I will have an apply that takes a single argument, 
Why the 2nd Int in Function1[Int, Int] when my apply is built to only take a single Int argument?

Please explain.

Comment: as a side note you can also write `extends (Int => Int)`

Comment: Yeah.  I see that now.  That syntax makes the magic more clear.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It's return type. `Function1[Int, Int]` is the same as `Int => Int`. It takes one `Int` and returns one `Int`.

We can write simplified [`scala.Function1`](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/#scala.Function1) like this:

```
trait Function1[T1, R]{
  def apply(v1: T1): R
}
```

Comment: +1 I would also point out how the signature for apply is in fact taking a Int argument (m) and returning a Int

Comment: Oh, I get it.  Function2[Int,Int,Double] would be def apply(v1: Int, v2: Int): Double and so on.